# Fetch only one field in php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have the following code

```
if (isset($_POST['change'])) {
    $current = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['current']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);

    if(strlen($password) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }
    if($password != $cpassword) {
        $error = true;
        $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
    }

    if(mysqli_fetch_field(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['usr_id'] . "' LIMIT 1")) != md5($current)) {
        $error = true;
        $confirm_error = "Your actual password is not correct";
    }
}
```

The problem is here:

```
mysqli_fetch_field(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['usr_id'] . "' LIMIT 1"))
```

It gives me the error

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /.../password.php on line 27

I have tried with

`mysql_result(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['usr_id'] . "' LIMIT 1"), 0)`

but it not works, it gives me

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_result() in /.../password.php:27

I don't want to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` and a `while` loop. I have searched for a function or something similar and i have found something but nothing worked for me.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password'])` you know that that stands to backfire.

Comment: It may have nothing to do with `mysqli_fetch_field`. Dump `$_SESSION['usr_id']`, and separate your mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_field statements. And of course mysql_result won't work, it's not a mysqli function.

Comment: `I don't want to use mysqli_fetch_array() and a while loop.` .... why?

Comment: Your code is unsafe to use; especially the password function you're using `md5($current)`. Do **not** put this online. I'd call this a "blessing in disguise" that your code failed.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_field` gets info about the column not getting the value! Since you are using the procudual version of mysqli why not create an function you need (where mysqli_fetch_array is used) like `function getFieldFromQuery($query,$fieldname,$con);`

Comment: *"I have tried with mysql_result(mysqli_query($con...."* - That's because you can't mix different mysql apis. And Lord only knows which api is used to connect with and what the origins of the POST arrays are. I feel you should abandon this code and start fresh with a prepared statement and `password_hash()` / `password_verify()`. There are a lot  of good/better/safer scripts out there.

Comment: Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is the best solution for you but base on what you are asking you might want to use mysqli_fetch_assoc.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['usr_id'] . "' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

 if( $row['password']!= md5($current)) {
        $error = true;
        $confirm_error = "Your actual password is not correct";
 }
```

Mention in the comments below that you should use parameterized query. For users password use password hashing library like http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ OR built in [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function in PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7.

To parameterize your current query and avoid possible sql injection attacks try the following code.

```
$mysqliConnection = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_dbname");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqliConnection->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqliConnection->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqliConnection->connect_error;
}

$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqliConnection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['usr_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($password);
$stmt->store_result();
$row = $stmt->fetch()
```

Now you could use $password variable to check the password hashing you have used. I hope this helps.

Comment: it looks like i misunderstood the question and got downvoted with out reason. Would you care to explain why so that I could improve?

Comment: If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Anyone who downvotes *has* a reason, they may not chose to comment. The question of comments + downvotes has been discussed ad nauseum on Meta. Many folks just choose to DV and move on. Many offer advice. Many try to light the path for newbies. Teaching someone to continue to use outdated methods along with unsafe practices is now more likely to get you downvotes as many have become hyper-aware teach true best practices.

Comment: Hi @JayBlanchard I understand what you mean and for me its better to give comments for downvote so that answers will be improve. I was so focus on helping the op to get what he wants. I should have mention that its not the best answer and avoid non standard coding. Thanks for letting me know will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation for [mysqli_fetch_field()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php):

> Returns the definition of one column of a result set as an object. Call this function repeatedly to retrieve information about all columns in the result set.

This function doesn't return the *value* in one column of the result set, it returns metadata about that column. Like the column name, the table name, the data type, the max length, etc.

If you capture the field and dump it, you see:

```
$passhash = mysqli_fetch_field(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = '" . $usr_id . "' LIMIT 1"));
print_r($passhash);
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => password
    [orgname] => password
    [table] => users
    [orgtable] => users
    [def] => 
    [db] => test
    [catalog] => def
    [max_length] => 32
    [length] => 65535    <-- I used TEXT for the password column 
    [charsetnr] => 8
    [flags] => 16
    [type] => 252
    [decimals] => 0
)
```

Notice that it's returned as an object, not a scalar value. So you can't compare it to your `md5($current)` directly. Nor does it even have the value you're looking for.

Here's how I would write the code you're trying to do:

```
$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
$stmt->bind_param($stmt, "i", $_SESSION['usr_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$match = false;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['password'] == md5($current) {
        $match = true;
    }
}
if (!$match) {
    $error = true;
    $confirm_error = "Your actual password is not correct";
}
```

Your other error:

> Call to undefined function mysql_result()

The [mysql_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) function is deprecated and it has been removed in PHP 7. It wouldn't work together with mysqli_query() anyway, since it's part of a different API, and these two APIs don't mix.

[mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) (note the mysqli, not mysql) is the name of a resource class, not a function.